# How can I RETURN Axios error to client? (not only logging)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, axios, http-status-code-404

I know this has been asked many times but what I am facing is a really annoying problem.

I have my server which returns error string with status code 500. When i use axios and catch the error, i can log it easily, but when i return it, i can try everything but its gives me undefined, or it doesn't append anything.

```js
export const submitCheckout = async (betImport, ticket_id, token) => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: rootUrl + "bets/checkout/" + ticket_id,
    headers: {
      "x-auth-token": token,
    },
    data: {
      betImport,
    },
  }).catch(({ response }) => {
    console.log(response.status) //this works
    return response;
  });
  return res.data;
};

//HERE I CALL THE FUNCTION

const res = await submitCheckout(sum, ticket_id, token);
  //here i can access only the body of the error, even if i try to append something to it. 
    if (res.ticket_id) {
      emptyTicket();
      setmodal({
        show: true,
        title: "SUCCESS",
        subtitle: "BET PLACED",
        maxwin: `${res.maxWin}`,
        ticketId: `${res.ticket_id}`,
        account_sum: `${res.account_sum}`,
      });
      ModifyAccountUser(user, res.account_sum);
    } else {
      setmodal({
        title: "ERROR",
        show: true,
        status: `${res.status}`,
        error: `${res}`,
      });
      if (res.toString().includes("Token")) history.push("/login");
    }
    
    //WHAT I WANT TO DO
   export const submitCheckout = async (betImport, ticket_id, token) => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: rootUrl + "bets/checkout/" + ticket_id,
    headers: {
      "x-auth-token": token,
    },
    data: {
      betImport,
    },
  }).catch(({ response }) => {
    return {...response, response.status}; //this returns the body only, 
    return {res: response, status: response.status}; //this crashes,
    return response + "-"+ response.status}; //this was my desperation attack and failed as well
  });
  return res.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw an error and put your response inside it as a string. Then access it in your promise with error.message:

```js
async function foo(){
try{
const res = await ax.post("url", {params})
return res
}
catch(err){
throw new Error("my error message")
}
}

//then

foo()
.then(res=> do stuff)
.catch(err=> err.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
try {
    let res = await Axios({
      method: {method},
      URL: {url},
      data: {body}
    });

    let data = res.data;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response); // this is the main part. Use the response property from the error object

    return error.response;
  }
```